# String cutting off during insert query

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

Why is this doing what it's doing?

Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sourceInsert'])) {
        $url = $db_con3->real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
        $desc = $db_con3->real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
        echo '$urlbefore is ' . $url . '<br />'; ///for troubleshooting
        $result = $db_con3->query("INSERT INTO gdrive_links (evalid, userid, url, desc) VALUES ('$evalid', '$id', '$url', '$desc')");

        echo '$urlafter is ' . $url . '<br />'; ///For troubleshooting
        echo $db_con3->error; ///For troubleshooting
    }
?>
```

HTML output:

```
$urlbefore is https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0tcjQ3FxlB6dWlMTkNQVjBwVDA/edit?usp=sharing
$urlafter is https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0tcjQ3FxlB6dWlMTkNQVjBwVDA/edit?usp=sharing
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('1284017', '1', 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0tcjQ3FxlB6dWlMT' at line 1
```

So the string is fine before and after the query string, but in the query it's being cut off at the 49th character. Am I missing something dumb? It looks like my query syntax is correct...

Comment: You have `(evalid, userid, url, desc) VALUES ('$evalid', '$id', '$url', '$desc')`, shouldn't that be `(evalid, userid, url, desc) VALUES ('$evalid', '$userid', '$url', '$desc')`?

Comment: `desc` is mysql keyword...rename to any other

Comment: no, the userid for this table is the $id for the user.

Comment: Tamil Selvan THANK YOU!  that was it.

Comment: note to self...do NOT use desc as a field name, EVER...:)

Comment: @Rich701 You can, but after escaping it. :)

Comment: +1 voting up for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because, you have a [**reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), unescaped.

```
$result = $db_con3->query("INSERT INTO gdrive_links (`evalid`, `userid`, `url`, `desc`) VALUES ('$evalid', '$id', '$url', '$desc')");
```

You need to escape them using backticks, this way. `desc` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Escape them like above.

Comment: I just changed the field name file_desc and all is working, thanks.

Comment: Welcome! If you would like to use `desc` itself, you can use this way. You can copy the code in my answer and paste it in your app to make it work. :)

Comment: using an unescaped reserved word should trigger an error, not  insert a partial string

Comment: @Dagon It did trigger an error. Please see the output.

Comment: oh he meant the string was truncated in the error message; well that was quite irrelevant :-)