# PHP MySQL (MariaDB) Query Cut Off

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

My MySQL statement is not running properly on my PHP page. The statement itself appears to be getting cut off. Others have had similar problems—as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765485/string-cutting-off-during-insert-query) as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)—but they were using reserved words in their statements.

But according to what I can see [from the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html), I don't believe I am using any.

When I run this query:

```
$ticket_query = "
SELECT  myticket.number,
    myticket.status,
    myticket.created,
    myticket.source,
    myticket.ticket_id,
    myticket.lastresponse,
    myticket__cdata.subject,
    myticket__cdata.priority,
FROM myticket
    INNER JOIN myticket__cdata
    ON myticket.ticket_id = myticket__cdata.ticket_id
WHERE   (myticket.status = 'open');";
```

I get this error on my PHP page:

> There was an error running the ticket query [You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM myticket INNER JOIN
>   myticket__cdata ON myticket.ticket_id = o' at line 9]

However, when I run it formatted like this:

```
$ticket_query = "
SELECT  myticket.number,
    myticket.status,
    myticket.created,
    myticket.source,
    myticket.ticket_id,
    myticket.lastresponse,
    myticket__cdata.subject,
    myticket__cdata.priority,
FROM myticket INNER JOIN myticket__cdata ON myticket.ticket_id = myticket__cdata.ticket_id
WHERE   (myticket.status = 'open');";
```

I get this error on my PHP page:

> There was an error running the ticket query [You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM myticket INNER JOIN
>   myticket__cdata ON myticket.ticket_id = osti_t' at line 9]

I'm kind of stuck here and I'm assuming it is something small I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had an extra comma just before the FROM

```
$ticket_query = "
SELECT  myticket.number,
    myticket.status,
    myticket.created,
    myticket.source,
    myticket.ticket_id,
    myticket.lastresponse,
    myticket__cdata.subject,
    myticket__cdata.priority /*removed comma from here*/
FROM myticket
    INNER JOIN myticket__cdata
    ON myticket.ticket_id = myticket__cdata.ticket_id
WHERE   (myticket.status = 'open');";
```

Comment: Unbelievably embarrassing. Thank you.